# Pandas Dataframe - replace NaN with 0 if column value condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have searched all around the internet and tried many methods before making this post, I have a dataframe where I want to:

- Replace NaN value of **TGT_COLUMN_SCALE** to 0 If **TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE** is equals to NUMERIC.

[image: my dataframe]

Kindly help me out with this issue.

I tried this code but it's not working:

```
df["TGT_COLUMN_SCALE"] = np.where(df["TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE"] == "NUMERIC", 'NaN', 0)
```

Comment: df.loc[(df.TARGET_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE == "NUMERIC") & (df.TARGET_COLUMN_SCALE.isnull()), "TARGET_COLUMN_SCALE"] = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE" : ["DATE", "NUMERIC", "STRING", "NUMERIC"],
    "TGT_COLUMN_SCALE" : [np.NaN, np.NaN, 4.0, 5.0]
})
```

Replace

```
df.loc[(df.TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE == "NUMERIC") & (df.TGT_COLUMN_SCALE.isnull()), "TGT_COLUMN_SCALE"] = 0
```

Result:

```
    TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE    TGT_COLUMN_SCALE
0   DATE    NaN
1   NUMERIC 0.0
2   STRING  4.0
3   NUMERIC 5.0
```

Comment: It replaced NaN with zero and all other values with NaN. That's not what I need.

Comment: It didnt.. it replaces only when `TARGET_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE` is `Numerical` and `TARGET_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE` is nan.

Comment: Look at index 3, `TARGET_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE` is set to `NUMERIC` and value is 5.0. it has not changed. only index 1 has changed.

Comment: It created new column and then did this - https://i.imgur.com/zAqOcVV.png that's not what I need.

Comment: Thats because you simply copy pasted the solution. Change the column name based on your input

Comment: Updated the column names in the answer as well

Comment: Thats just a sample input. To make sure that the rows are not changed.

Comment: On the first place, if you can just share a sample input while writing the question, it will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: I have already shared a screenshot with the sample input. Not sure if you are able to see it or not. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` will take the first option as the value in case the condition is true, else the second. You need to replace the order of `nan` and 0

```
df["TGT_COLUMN_SCALE"] = np.where((df["TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE"] == "NUMERIC") & (df["TGT_COLUMN_SCALE"].isnull()), 0, df["TGT_COLUMN_SCALE"])
```

Comment: It's not working now. It's still showing NaN.

Comment: @AviThour you need to assign the returned value, updated the answer.

Comment: it replaced all other values which were not NaN with 0 aswell.

Comment: this is what your code did. https://i.imgur.com/IaBpjZI.png It replaced non-nan value to zero also.

Comment: @AviThour but this is what you asked *Replace NaN value of TGT_COLUMN_SCALE to 0 If TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE is equals to NUMERIC*

Comment: yes but your code is replacing 4.0 to 0 as well. Got the point?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use loc to select the columns and then you use fillna to replace values:

```
df.loc[df.TGT_COLUMN_SCALE == "NUMERIC",
       "TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE"] = df.loc[df.TGT_COLUMN_SCALE == "NUMERIC", "TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE"].fillna(0)
```

### Full code

```
TGT_COLUMN_SCALE = ('DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', 'NUMERIC', 'NUMERIC')
TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE = (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(TGT_COLUMN_SCALE, TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE)),
                  columns=['TGT_COLUMN_SCALE', 'TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE'])
df.loc[df.TGT_COLUMN_SCALE == "NUMERIC",
       "TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE"] = df.loc[df.TGT_COLUMN_SCALE == "NUMERIC", "TGT_COLUMN_DATA_TYPE"].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Why are you including Date, Timestamp in this? I just want to change Numeric value of NaN with Zero. Can you provide any simpler method?

Comment: You just have to copy the last line, as you can see by copying the full code, it works.

Comment: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: it's just a warning, you should get rid of it with: `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`